# loading images on a page load using a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to load images when the 'add_more_services_new.html' page loads using a custom directive. If a condition is true load an image and if the condition is false load another image. Below  is my custom directive.

```
function addMoreServicesFn(){
 return {
        restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/add_more_services_new.html',

        controller:function($scope, $rootScope){
            $scope.hide = function(){
                $rootScope.modalShown = !$rootScope.modalShown; 
            }
        }
```

How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive here,

create a function to get the image `src` based on condition like,

```
controller:function($scope, $rootScope){
        $scope.hide = function(){
            $rootScope.modalShown = !$rootScope.modalShown; 
        };

        $scope.getSrc = function() {
            if(condition_statement) {
                 return "images/a.jpg";
            } else {
                 return "images/b.jpg";
            }
        }
    }
```

in `add_more_services_new.html`

```
<img ng-src="{{ getSrc() }}" />
```

Comment: Thank you @KalhanToress :D
but how to call this function when my template is loading?

Comment: umm put the `<img ng-src="{{ getSrc() }}" />` in the  `add_more_services_new.html` after this `ng-src` will call the `getSrc()` function in the controller and get the `src` based on condition. :)

Answer (score 0):

For achieving the same thing you could handle this logic on `ng-src` itself with `{{}}` interpolation directive.

```
<img ng-src="{{modalShown?'/img/someImg.jpg':'/img/someOtherImg.jpg'}}" alt="Some Title"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to call this when the template is loading which I defined in my custom directive..

Comment: @SupunWimukthi are you able accomplish this?

Comment: @SupunWimukthi does it helped you?

Comment: I can't put the code like this in the html. I want to return from a function in my custom directive like my friend @K.Toress explained but thank you very much for your effort :)